Connecting google spreadsheet to Discord API
I can't manage to fetch the discord global_username from members on my servers when using their <@UserID> in a google spreadsheet script. More below.
Hello, first time posting and I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm trying to connect through a discord bot my google spreadsheet to a server discord in which I've got admin perms.
The objective here is simple and shouldn't be hard, what I want is that by linking my spreadsheet to Discord's API with the bot token, I want to input in a cell the <@UserID> and have it update the cell to its right so it shows the global_username linked to said UserID.
I've been on it for more time than I'd like to admit and I could use some help.
Here's the code I've had:
const DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'MY TOKEN';

function getDiscordUsername(userID) {
  if (typeof userID !== 'string' || userID.trim() === '') {
    return 'Invalid UserID';
  }

  if (userID.startsWith('<@') && userID.endsWith('>')) {
    userID = userID.slice(2, -1);
  } else if (userID.startsWith('@')) {
    userID = userID.slice(1);
  }

  const url = `https://discord.com/api/v10/users/${userID}`;
  
  const options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': `Bot ${DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN}`
    }
  };
  
  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      return json.username + '#' + json.discriminator;
    } else {
      return 'User not found';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return 'Error fetching user';
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e || !e.range) {
    console.error('No event object or range found.');
    return;
  }

  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();


  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const range = e.range;
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    

    if (sheetName !== 'Feuille1' && sheetName !== 'Feuille2') {
      const userID = e.value;
      if (userID) {
        const username = getDiscordUsername(userID);
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).setValue(username);
      }
    }
  });
}


Are you able to able to get a response from Discord's API through something like Postman using your token and userId?

Yep, gave it a try with curl and I've succesfully had a response with all the user fields.

I have a couple of pointers after trying to reproduce your project.
I hope this helps!
I'm not too familiar with the Discord API, but the first thing I noticed is that the error handling in your code is obscuring important information.
You should log the exception you're receiving, as well the request response code and the request payload when an error is returned.
try {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    ...
  } else {
    console.log(response.getResponseCode());
    console.log(response.getContentText());
    return 'User not found';
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  return 'Error fetching user';
}

I was able to set up a project where the user object is successfully returned with either '@me' or the snowflake id for my bot.
Hopefully these help you out.
1.- Apps Script UrlFetchApp permission.
The first exception I faced was due to the lack of permission to use the UrlFetchApp class.
Notably, it cannot be used with a simple onEdit trigger[1], make sure you are using an installable trigger.
This is because you need an explicit scope to use it [2] which cannot be authorized if you are using a simple trigger.

This service requires the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request scope

To fix this, rename your onEdit function and use an installable trigger.
I.E

I renamed it to onEditInstallable
Go to the triggers section of your project.
Click add a new trigger
Select your onEditInstallable function
Make it execute onEdit from spreadsheet.

2.- Malformed request to the discord API causing 403 internal network error response.
I had to remove a portion of your code which modifies the userId input value.
Because I'm using either '@me' or the numeric snowflake Id as input, that portion would malform my input causing the discord API to return 403.
if (userID.startsWith('<@') && userID.endsWith('>')) {
  userID = userID.slice(2, -1);
} else if (userID.startsWith('@')) {
  userID = userID.slice(1);
}

I am not sure that particular request you are using would work to return the user object, as the discord API reference notes that the user get request must be made with either '@me' or the user snowflake id [3][4].
I also added the parameter 'muteHttpExceptions' so that I could inspect the full response payload, but it's not strictly necessary.
At the end my apps script code is the following:
const DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'XXXX';

function getDiscordUsername(userID) {
  if (typeof userID !== 'string' || userID.trim() === '') {
    return 'Invalid UserID';
  }

  const url = `https://discord.com/api/v10/users/${userID}`;
  
  const options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': `Bot ${DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN}`
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  
  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      console.log(json);
      return json.username + '#' + json.discriminator;
    } else {
      console.log(response.getResponseCode());
      console.log(response.getContentText());
      return 'User not found';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return 'Error fetching user';
  }
}

function onEditInstalled(e) {
  if (!e || !e.range) {
    console.error('No event object or range found.');
    return;
  }

  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();


  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const range = e.range;
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();


    if (sheetName !== 'Feuille1' && sheetName !== 'Feuille2') {
      const userID = e.value;
      if (userID) {
        const username = getDiscordUsername(userID);
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).setValue(username);
      }
    }
  });
}

With my appsscript.json as follows:
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}

References:
Simple Triggers > Getting Started > onEdit 
[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started
Class UrlFetchApp 
[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
Get User 
[3] https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user
User Object 
[4] https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object
